Why does USB cable make a difference when connecting to USB Hub?
I have a cheap old USB 3.0 SS powered hub that I would like to use with my 2024 MBP M3 Max, which of course only has USB-C/TB4. I'm connecting an audio interface and a USB musical keyboard via the hub.
When I use the supplied USB-A SS cable and use a cheap USB-A to C adapter to connect to my TB4 port, it works perfectly, as it did with my older Macs.
However, in trying to simplify things a bit, I purchase a Cable Creations USB A 3.2 to USB-C/TB3 cable, and using it, nothing is recognized!
I thought I had thoroughly researched the cable, and it states : "USB 3.2 10Gbps Data Transfer - Gen2 USB 3.2 Type-A to Type-C Cable supports super speed data transmission".
I thought with the "super speed" designation, I was golden.
Apparently not.
Can someone please explain (feel free to get into the technical nitty-gritty) why one cable will work and another will not?
EDIT: I'm specifically looking for information about the physical properties of the cables, their connectors, their pinouts etc that makes them suitable for one standard or another.

Do you have multiple of the same cable? Sometimes you just get a bad cable.

If you are looking for diagnostic help, please tell us exactly what hub and what cable - preferably with links to where we can find the specs.

@Gilby, no, not looking for diagnostic help. Looking for an explanation why one cable might work and another not (excepting of course broken / damage / faulty cables). Is there different wiring?

Different cable, different supported standards. "SuperSpeed" is USB 3.0 (5 Gb/s). Don't confuse connector type (USB-A and USB-C) with data standards like USB 3.2

Thanks @Gilby but my question is specifically asking to EXPLAIN WHY a given physical cable supports a given standard. WHAT is physically different about a cable that is, for example USB 3.2 vs an older standard?
For example, I get that a purely charging cable rated for higher amperage charging needs a lower gauge wire to prevent overheating.
What is physically different about a cable that supports one standard but not another?
